# C# How to make the deserialized JSON import public?

Tags: c#, list

I have deserialized a JSON file and im not able to access the List myImport outside the using statement. Inside the using statement everything works fine. How to make the List accessible outside?

```
public class ImportJSON
{
    static public void ImportMyFile()
    {
        string myFilePath = @"C:\adf\af\afd\af\afs\CoordData.json";

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myFilePath))
        {
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            List<Coord> myImport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coord>>(json);
        }

        foreach (var item in myImport)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID : " + item.iD);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare it before `using`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the list outside of the using statement.

```
List<Coord> myImport = new List<Coord>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myFilePath))
{
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    myImport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coord>>(json);
}

foreach (var item in myImport)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID : " + item.iD);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thansk for support :)

Comment: Stupid question, but how to make it also available outside the method? If i declare the list outside the method, i get an error inside the using statement 'myImport does not exist in the current contex...

Comment: Make it static `static List<Coord> myImport = new List<Coord>();`